# Necesito tomar TD (html) en Django (vistas)

Tags: javascript, html, html5, python-3.x, django

Necesito ayuda respecto a **Django, HTML y javascript**, quiero tomar los valores del textContent desde la vista django, el problema es que cuando genero nuevas filas nose como decirle a Django(vista) que atrape esas filas generadas, aquí mi código:

**HTML**

```
<article style="width:100%">
    <form action="">
        <table id="tabla_venta">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6"><input type="submit" style="width:100%" value="Vender"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>MARCA</strong></td>
            <td><strong>MODELO</strong></td>
            <td><strong>PULGADAS</strong></td>
            <td><strong>PRECIO</strong></td>
            <td><strong>CANTIDAD</strong></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</article>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function agregar(posicion){
    if (document.getElementById('check'+posicion).checked == true) {

        var marca = document.getElementById('marca'+posicion).textContent
        var modelo = document.getElementById('modelo'+posicion).textContent
        var pulgadas = document.getElementById('pulgadas'+posicion).textContent
        var precio = document.getElementById('precio'+posicion).textContent
        var cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad'+posicion).textContent
                        
        var table = document.getElementById("tabla_venta");
        var row = table.insertRow(tabla_venta.rows.length);
        var row2 = table.insertRow(tabla_venta.rows.length);
        row.id = "fila"+posicion;
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0).textContent=marca;
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1).textContent=modelo;
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2).textContent=pulgadas;
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3).textContent=precio;
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4).innerHTML="<input type='number' min='1' max="+cantidad+" style='width:75px' />";

    }else{
        registro_eliminar = document.getElementById('fila'+posicion);
        registro_eliminar.parentNode.removeChild(registro_eliminar);
    }
}
```

Porfavor necesito ayuda con esto, muchas gracias!

Comment: No te entiendo muy bien, pero para enviarle datos a una vista de Django, puedes hacer peticiones AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolver mi problema, lo dejo por acá por si otra persona le ocurre mi error, igual se agradece Julio Cesar por responderme

```
def inicio(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    datosBD=Monitores.objects.all()
    contador=0
    lista=[]
    devolver=[]
    guardar=''

    for datos in datosBD:
        try:
            valor=request.POST.get('elemento'+str(contador))
            for separar in valor:
                if "¬" in separar:
                    lista.append(guardar)
                    guardar=""
                else:
                    guardar=guardar+separar
            contador+=1
            devolver.append(lista)
            lista=[]
        except:
            contador+=1
```